# unbind method from instance and bind to other instance

Tags: python, class, bind

I have read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bound-unbound-and-static-methods-in-python/). is it possible to change: `a1.show` to `a2.show`, I mean, change the orientation of the method to point to different instance.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def show(self):
        print(self.a)


a1 = A(1)
a2 = A(2)
mtd = staticmethod(a1.show)
mtd(a2)
```

I want to see `2` in console. I mean, for a normal method in class, change its instance, from `a1` to `a2`?

---

You may wonder why I do this, I have got a decorator to record what the instance has been through.

```py
class Data:

    def __init__(self):
        self.caches = []

    # do not call it outside of class, it is used to record procedure 
    def add_cache(self, val):
        self.caches.append(val)

    def clean_cache(self):
        self.caches = []

    def record(foo):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.add_cache({foo.__name__: {'args': args, 'kwargs': kwargs}})
            return foo(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```

Now, I can add this decorator to the function that needs to be recorded every call. For example, I want `linear` to be **recorded** but wrap.

```
class Data:
    def wrap(self):
        print('wrap')

    @record
    def linear(self, least_square=True):
        pass
```

Now, I am allowed to define a `simulate` function, which pass in another instance, and let it be through what this instance has been through.

But, my cache only recorded `foo.__name__`, which I need to write my own mapper to decide which function to call. This is complex. Therefore, instead of recording `foo.__name__`, I want to directly record `foo` and change its orientation from self to other.

Hope I have explained with enough clarity. I will be so glad if you give me a hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed python object's methods are not bonded to instance, which if I store `foo` in `record`, I need to pass in `self` as first argument.

```py
    def simulate(self, other):
        for di in self.caches:
            kk = list(di.keys())[0]
            vv = list(di.values())[0]
            kk(other, *vv['args'], **vv['kwargs'])
        return self
```

This works out.